# I can't access a folder on server

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a folder on server to get the files in it.

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\108.163.190.98:3306\home\mybizscard\Ads\")))
{
    list.Add(filename);
}
```

but I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

what is the problem ?? and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Can you say what `object`is null and throws the exception?

Comment: Is your `List<string>` initialized with `List<string> list = new List<string>();`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are giving right path I think it should be

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\108.163.190.98\home\mybizscard\Ads\")))
            {
                list.Add(filename);
            }
```

Comment: @Maya  - Did you find your answer??

Answer (score 0):

Seems you did not initialize your string array.

```
var files = new string[];
files = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\108.163.190.98:3306\home\mybizscard\Ads\"));
foreach (string filename in files)
            {
                list.Add(filename);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `MapPath` doesn't do what you think it does. It is used within ASP.NET applications to map a relative path to the web root (get an absolute path for the relative path).

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.

You can not use it within a desktop application. The question is why you want to do that anyway? A UNC path can already be used like any other path (it may not contain a port, however):

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\108.163.190.98\home\mybizscard\Ads\")))
{
    list.Add(filename);
}
```

That is: If the user running the application as the required rights on that folder.